# Find positive integer $x$ where $x^{13} = 21982145917308330487013369$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's easy to find out the solution, which $x = 89$, by using calculation. But is there any way to solve this problem step by step? Any trick can use?

Answer (score 8):

There are tricks that can only be used when you know that the answer is an integer.

For example, by counting the number of digits, you can show that the answer is smaller than $100$.

Then we calculate the number mod $9$ (by adding its digits) and see that the answer is congruent to $8$ mod $9$.

A similar calculation mod $11$ shows that the answer is congruent to $1$ mod $11$.

Using Chinese remainder theorem, we know that the answer is congruent to $89$ mod $99$.

Since it's smaller than $100$, the only possibility is $89$.

Comment: Excuse me, could you please explain more how to find out 89 through Chinese remainder theorem. Thank you!

Comment: @Solitarie Basically speaking, the idea is that if $a,b$ are two coprime numbers, and you know the remainder that a fixed number leaves when it's divide by $a$ and $b$, that uniquely tells you what's the remainder the number leaves when it's divided by $ab$ (which is the LCM of $a$ and $b$). Now, the point is that we found the remainder of $x$ upon division by $9$ and upon division by $11$. We *know* what is the remainder when such a number is divided by $99$. To find that number :

Comment: we start by seeing numbers which satisfy only one of the conditions. For example, numbers which are $1$ more than a multiple of $11$ would leaves remainders $1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89$. Of these, *only* $89$ has the *additional* property of being $8$ more than a multiple of $9$. The CRT tells you that $89$ is the *ONLY* possible remainder. So your number has two digits and leaves a remainder of $89$ upon division by $99$. You can see how the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

You have $$x^{13} \approx 2 \cdot 10^{25}\\
13 \log_{10}x \approx 25.3\\
\log_{10}x \approx 1.95$$
means $x$ is pretty close to $100$ but less.
The ones digit of $x$ is $9$ to get the $13^{th}$ power to end in $9$.  This gets you to try $99, 89$ and bingo.

Answer (score 0):

$Hint$: Use Fermat's Little Theorem , for any $x\in\mathbb N$ and $p$ is a prime number . $x^p$ ≡ $x(mod ⠀p)$